# How to start decreasing a duration stored in Firebase as string? Please see details

Tags: java, android, firebase, countdowntimer, timeunit

I'm developing an android app and I have opted users to choose the duration and then I store it on Firebase as a string like this:

```
hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
```

It is getting saved as `1:30:00`.

Now, I am retrieving it from Firebase and showing it to user but I want to show it as a decreasing duration.

How can I do that?

Please let me know.